# Pulled wires and didn't take a picture, now breaker will not shut off power. Help

Tags: circuit-breaker

Now I've wired it from black power to white switch to black wire other room, then to light socket Wires neutral power to neutral other room hooked thos Then black to poweron fixturre

Comment: Your word picture is about as useful as the picture you didn't take - which is to say, it's not very clear at all. If the breaker doesn't shut off power, something is very wrong or you have the wrong breaker for the circuit.

Comment: If breaker will not shut off power, you either have the wrong breaker you are trying or the breaker is bad.

Comment: For what it’s worth, two circuits can exist in one box.

Comment: How many cables are in the box?